# Fazer um gráfico no R (ggplot) semelhante aos gráficos de barra do Excel

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como posso fazer um gráfico no R (ggplot) semelhante a este gráfico do excel?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma tabela em formtao csv com esses dados. Eu consegui subi para o R essa tabela, mas agora não sei como fazer esse gráfico usando o R.

o link da tabela: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RqQSlupktWMqAD44xs9GgT0UXPyhdnU6/view?usp=sharing

Update:
Segue os dados da tabela em formato de texto separador ";":

```
Estudo;Vegetação_Nativa;Pastagem;Corpo_Hídrico;Solo_Exposto;Silvicultura;Agricultura
GEOMS 2007;15,71;83,99;0,31;0;0;0
Plano de Manejo 2008;16,99;82,69;0,31;0;0,02;0
Garcia et. al, (2014) - 2011;15,74;76,27;0,3;4,11;3,55;0
Oliveira et. al. (2017);18,24;23,8;0,3;49,47;8,2;0
Finck et al. (2020) - 2018;22,63;62;0,4;6,69;8,28;0
MapBiomas 2019;14,9;75,34;0,26;0,06;8,2;1,13
CART - Sentinel2 2020;21,39;67,89;0,24;0;10,56;0
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: ola Lucas, na verdade nao coloquei código. a primeira imagem refere-se a tabela que possuo. a segunda imagem é aonde desejo chegar, mas não sei como fazer no R. abçs

Comment: Sim. Para replicar o seu problema seria ideal que vc disponibilizase os dados em formato de texto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv2('./Tabela_areas_referencias_porcent_2.csv')

df_pivoted <- pivot_longer(
  data = df,
  cols = c("Vegetação_Nativa", "Pastagem","Corpo_Hídrico",
           "Solo_Exposto","Silvicultura","Agricultura"),
  values_to = 'Valores',
  names_to = 'Vegetacao'
)

df_pivoted %>%
  ggplot(aes(Estudo, Valores, fill = Vegetacao)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 15, hjust=1))
```

Você pode pivotar os dados e utilizar o ggplot.

1. carregamos os dados
2. criamos o data.frame pivotado
3. plotamos o gráfico

[image: graph]

Comment: ola lmonferrari, testei o seu código aqui rodou certinho aqui. Teria alguma forma de mudar as cores? grato pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `scale_fill_manual`, após o theme você adiciona um + e adiciona essa linha: `scale_fill_manual(values = c('#D6F9DD','#99F7AB','#ABDF75','#60695C','#C0D7BB','#644536'))`. Você pode mudar os códigos hex para as cores que te agradar. Abraço!